# ImportError: cannot import name parse_url for slackclient

Tags: python, bots, slack

I'm trying to create a slackbot for my raspberry pi. I got it to work on my MacBook, but on the raspberry pi the slackclient is causing issues. I have manually installed it and installed it using 'pip'. Both times I get errors that are pointed at the installation file. I've attached a screenshot of the exact errors I get when running the python code.

[image]

Comment: Please copy and paste the text rather than posting a screenshot. It makes it easier for future readers to find the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you might have an old version of `requests` installed.

If you installed `requests` with pip, you could try upgrading:

```
pip install --upgrade requests
```

If you installed requests using `apt` or `apt-get` then I would avoid trying to upgrade with pip. Try creating a virtual environment and installing requests there.

Comment: Unfortunately updating requests did not fix the issue. The same error still shows when I try to run the script.

Comment: What version of requests/urllib3 have you installed?

Comment: Requests version 2.4.3 and urllib3 version1.9.1

Comment: 2.4.3 was released in 2014. The current version is 2.18.1. The current version of `slackclient` [requires](https://github.com/slackapi/python-slackclient/blob/master/setup.py#L55) >=2.11. As I said before, jf you can't upgrade using `apt`, or `apt-get`, then I suggest creating a virtual environment and install the latest version of requests using pip.